# How to save image as 32-bit BMP?

Tags: windows, images, adobe-photoshop, bmp

I have an image with alpha channel, I need to save it as 32-bit BMP. However, Microsoft Paint doesn't allow saving as 32-bit, only 24-bit. I have Photoshop CS5, but it also doesn't have the option to save as 32-bit BMP.

Any solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Photoshop >> Menu >> File >> Save As >> Choose format BMP in dropdown box >> Save button >> Choose 32-bit format >> OK button

However, photoshop will save the image as XRGB. In case the image has alpha channel (as ARGB), must use another tool:
http://www.qualibyte.com/pixelformer/

In Pixelformer, choose Menu >> File >> Export, Choose export file type as .bmp, Click 'Save', the following BMP options dialog should be shown, choose 32bit ARGB:
[image]

Comment: Well... Pixelformer gives me an XRGB anyway, do I need some special save procedure?

Comment: XRGB means leading zero, ARGB means leading alpha

Comment: I know that, however alpha is not included.

Comment: see the screenshot i've just added

Comment: I don't know why, but result doesn't contain alpha for me..

Comment: you need to convert the transparency to actual alpha channel shown in the channels tab in order to unlock the ARGB8 format for BMP and TGA

Answer (score 1):

Paint.Net supports 32-bit ARGB bitmaps via a plugin available in the [Paint.Net forum](https://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/11201-alpha-32bits-bitmap-support-for-paintnet/#entry308033).

To install the plugin:

- exit Paint.Net
- download the zip
- extract the dll
- copy the extracted dll to `C:\Program Files\Paint.NET\FileTypes`

As noted in the forum post, you need to rename files to *.bmpx before opening them in Paint.Net to avoid conflict with the default BMP filetype handler.